# jQuery get multiple rel values from anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get multiple rel values from a single anchor in jQuery or generally in JavaScript without splitting the rel into an array?

For example, in the case of an anchor having two rel attributes delimited by the standard space:

```
<a id='a' class='b' rel='9 9' href='#'>Link</a>
```

I can get each by using:

```
$('.b').click(function(e) {    
    /* ... */

    var rels = $(this).prop('rel').split("_"); 

    $('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_t]').val( rels[0] );
    $('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_n]').val( rels[1] );

    /* ... */
});
```

But was wondering if something along the lines of might be valid?

```
$('.b').click(function(e) {    
    /* ... */

    $('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_t]').val( $(this).prop('rel[0]') );
    $('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_n]').val( $(this).prop('rel[1]') );

    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: No, you cant do that. You have to use the former method. You need to change `$(this).prop('rel').split("_");` to `$(this).prop('rel').split(" ");`

Comment: There is a space between the numbers, not an underscore. Why would you split by an underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's not valid. You'll have to split or do something similar. Not sure why you're trying to avoid splitting, though, there's no reason to.\

---

Edit: You could do this, which I don't think is that bad at all.

```
$('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_t]').val( $(this).prop("rel").split(" ")[0]);
$('form#form-stage-2 input[name=sleeve_n]').val( $(this).prop("rel").split(" ")[1]);
```

Comment: Mm. You've got as clean as you'll get already, really, sorry. Although... there's no reason to save the array in a variable. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no formal support for `rel` having multiple values in the way that, say, `class` can. Nothing's stopping you from putting spaces in there, but you'll have to handle them on  your own.